# MySQL: Update vs. Replace Into .... why can Replace Into be a parallel process?

Tags: mysql, replace, parallel-processing

In trying to optimize a query that does (Insert ... on duplicate key update) .... someone suggested I do "Replace Into" to optimize performance. I'm not 100% certain the difference other than ... "Replace Into" apparently may do an Insert, then Delete instead of a "True update" when called for.

Here's my question:

Only one "update" can be done on a Table at a time. If one client is checking if an Id "201" exists .... and so is another, there would be collision otherwise, right? Well, for whatever reason, that appears to be the case.

However, "Replace Into" can be a query executed 10-20 times, however many times, in parallel at the same time, without error.

I'm not certain why this is the case.

Also, would the caveat in multiple parallel "Replace Into" queries be that the data being parallel "upserted" better not be order dependent?

I mean for a single 'update' statement ... if the data is time-ordered (like the current status of a particular building ... is is new, old, blown up?) ... then the last ordered data would 'survive' the update.

However for a parallel "Replace Into" process .... all of the sudden the order of updates is mostly chaos .... unless each 'update batch' contains unique keys. Does that make sense?

Would be great if someone could confirm this is correct, or incorrect.

Comment: Are you using MyISAM or InnoDB?

Comment: Wait a second. Is your question about `REPLACE` vesus `INSERT` or `REPLACE` versus `UPDATE`?

Comment: MyISAM uses table-level locks. There's very little parallelism possible.

Comment: `REPLACE` is generally considered worse than `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` because of the index modifications that have to be done for the `DELETE` and `INSERT` steps of `REPLACE`.

Comment: Ha ... actually it turns out multiple Updates can be done at once in this database ... I could have sworn it locked me out before .... well jeez, now I'm confused as ever. I thought 'update' queries were usually run sequentially .... I guess can you can run them in parallel as long as you know there won't be slightly-less-new data replacing slightly-more new data for a given record. But yeah ... I guess insert ... on duplicate would require less overhead. When would someone use Replace Into, then?

Comment: There's little reason to use `REPLACE INTO`. It's just an older feature that existed before they added `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. See the history here: http://www.percona.com/blog/2007/01/18/insert-on-duplicate-key-update-and-replace-into/

Comment: *actually it turns out multiple Updates can be done at once in this database*... no, they can't. In MyISAM, only one thread at a time can hold the necessary write lock, which is held at the table level.  Each update waits in line for its turn to write.

Comment: Well my etl tool pentaho seems to be doing it. Multiple parallel update steps on the same table. Verified number of rows updated and time reduced. I will double check the exact output and mysql query log. I remember this not working as little as a few months ago. Maybe something with myisam changed. That or somehow the unique index maybe allowed a loophole? Though if it locks at the table level... I'll double check what's happening. I know it's myisam and appears to be working.

Comment: FYI Michael --- followed up on this ... rows from the MyISAM table are being legitimately updated simultaenously by multiple 'update' queries. Well, I'm not exactly watching the low-level code, but firing '12 copies' of this update query is proving faster than 1 copy, and the results are accurate (in terms of updated content). Is it possible there's something else going on, like the 12 copies someone leveraging the internet connection to the database better and only doing 1 true update? Possibly, but seems doubtful.